# Should I flag non-questions (e.g. homework) or just vote to close & downvote?

Tags: discussion

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652992/linux-random-script

User isn't asking about a specific question, they have posted what appears to be a homework assignment and are just asking for someone to submit a script that satisfies the requirements.

I voted to close, downvoted, and flagged it for moderator attention, but it occurred to me that maybe I shouldn't have flagged it. What is the correct action?

I flagged it because I think it should be deleted, not just closed.

Here it is, for anyone with <10k rep, since it is now deleted.

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like it worked out exactly as it should have.

Comment: By flagging it for a moderator you are expecting us to step in where the community can't.  This isn't something that needs moderator attention and  IMO, this is not something we need to be involved with so don't flag it for us.

Comment: Homework or professional, work related questions should be treated the same. If it is homework but a clear, answerable question that may help others, upvote if you wish, answer if you can, or leave it be. If it is not a clear, specific question, downvote if you wish, vote to close if appropriate, and don't bother the mods for this (as stated previously). It can be deleted once closed if there are no (positive scored) answers.

Comment: Luckily, there were a handful of 20K+ users around to handle deletion of the question quickly.  There's no need for a moderator to step in here.

Comment: @nicael: That screenshot is from Grant who added it to this question.

Comment: @Bolt Ah, I see :)

Comment: This does bring up the point that there is no longer a "homework" or "no effort" closing code, so random closing codes must be used.  I think often people look for a suitable closing code and don't find one, so the question remains open.

Comment: @HotLicks Isn't the issue one of the fact that its homework being no more relevant than whether it's work related vs a spare time project?  When I find a solution to a programming problem I've experienced I don't find the distinction remotely interesting.

Comment: @Poldie - The issue is  that Opie copies the homework question into his SO question and says, in effect, "Do my homework for me."  And sometimes we see amateur "professional" programmers do the same -- "Write my program for me."  An SO question should be focused on a specific issue.

Comment: @HotLicks on Programmers.SE when such a question is asked its often closed as "unclear" - it is unclear what the nature of the problem that is within the scope of the site is. If the OP describes the problem context, the attempted solution and the difficulty that was encountered it doesn't matter if it is homework or not. If the OP just describes the problem context, there is no way to provide a good answer - the other two are necessary for good answers. Until those are provided it is unclear how best to answer the question.

Comment: @Makoto: Actually, I regard the delete-votes cast there as a waste: It's downvoted, closed, and unanswered, so the roomba will get it soon enough anyway.

Comment: @MichaelT - But people don't usually interpret "unclear" that way.  Usually the question is perfectly clear (eg,how do you add 2 + 2?) but it's a serious misuse of SO resources.

Comment: @Deduplicator:  If the roomba gets it or three 20K+ users get to it, I don't mind either way - the delete votes mean that the cruft disappears that much  faster from the site.

Answer (score 40):

The example you posted is definitely too broad.  (and already closed as such now)

If a user just copy/pastes the question from his assignment, chances are it's going to be too broad since s/he hasn't even attempted anything yet.

Homework questions are definitely allowed on SO though. Here's a recent [homework question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641085/random-values-when-using-merge-in-merge-sort-c) which seems to be a really well thought out and written question.

Like [@bluefeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286641/should-i-flag-non-questions-e-g-homework-or-just-vote-to-close-downvote#comment158225_286641) mentioned, you shouldn't be flagging these questions for moderator attention. So vote to close when applicable, and also downvote if you wish since that question obviously didn't show any research effort. *For users with less than 3k rep, flag to close the question as too broad or whatever's most applicable, but definitely don't flag for "other: needs moderator attention"*.

> I flagged it because I think it should be deleted, not just closed.

Questions with score of 0 or less, that are closed (except for dups), haven't been edited in the past 9 days and have no answers with score of 1 or more are automatically deleted. - [src](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519) So most likely those types of questions will be auto-deleted sooner than later.

Comment: That is rare gem of one asking good question about homework!

Comment: Good example there @bluet

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Bluet's excellent answer, I would note that the *reason* we have *On Hold* and not immediately close/delete is specifically to allow the poster to improve the question.  In the case of the question above, it's entirely possible the poster might follow the advice of the comments, and rather than pasting homework in, make the question specific to a problem they are having with the implementation.

As such, "Vote to Close" and downvote is *precisely* correct.  Deletion will happen *if it is not improved*, as a matter of course, either by the roomba or by other users who have that privilege.  Most questions that are deleted are deleted by users, not moderators.

Per MichaelT:

> 10k users deleted 16k questions, moderators deleted 20k questions, Roomba ate about 390k questions. Self deletes were about 237k

So fewer than 3% of all deletes were done by moderators, and about the same number were deleted by 10k users; the vast majority are deleted by the poster or by the roomba ([automatic process that cleans up many posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773)).

Comment: [Datas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221493/213963)! (granted from last year, but still data). 10k users deleted 16k questions, moderators deleted 20k questions, Roomba ate about 390k questions.  Self deletes were about 237k.

Comment: Ah, brilliant.  So my statistic was right-and-not-right (as I wasn't intending to include self deletes, but I'll take it!)